# The code below should take in integers separated by spaces and print them to the screen, but it is not printing the first integer?

Tags: java, for-loop, input, printing, integer

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestingCode {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {


    int n; 
    int integers;


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a single positive integer, n: ");
    n = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter n integers separated by spaces: ");
    integers = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    scan.close();
  }

}
```

Input

Enter a single positive integer, n:
   5

Enter n integers separated by spaces:
  1 2 3 4 5

Output
 2
 3
 4
 5

Expected output
It should print out
1
2
3
4
5

Comment: Remove `integers = scan.nextInt();`

Comment: Than you Elliott, that fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

The first integer is already read in with `integers = scan.nextInt();` before the `for` loop. But it is never printed out with `System.out.println`. So just remove that line as I commented it out below:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a single positive integer, n: ");
n = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter n integers separated by spaces: ");

// The below line read the first integer from input, but is never output with System.out.println().
// So just remove this line & reads in "n" number of integer in the "for" loop
// integers = scan.nextInt();

for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(input);
}

scan.close();
```